# How to use scrollTop in behat?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, behat, mink

I have a page, when I enter into that page it will show below part only, so  I want to scroll up to click one of the element present in the top of the page.How can I achieve that,I tried like below but its not working.

```
$this->getSession()->wait(5000, "jQuery('#page').animate({scrollTop: '-500px'}, 300)");
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an action like this:

```
$this->getSession()->executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,0);');
```

Answer (score 1):

With the following function, you can scroll to any element/area of a page:
Scenario:

/**
* @Given /^I scroll to x "([^"]*)" y "([^"]*)" coordinates of page$/
*/

```
public function iScrollToXYCoordinatesOfPage($arg1, $arg2)
{

    try {
        $this->getSession()->executeScript("(function(){window.scrollTo($arg1, $arg2);})();");
    }

    catch(Exception $e) {
        throw new \Exception("ScrollIntoView failed");
    }
}
```

The parameters in this case would be '0' and '0'